# plot regular graph when x axis data is inconsistent

Tags: statistics, data-processing

As an example, you have an API to access a sensor which measures how many lumens of light there are outside. Ideally you want to access it every hour on the hour so that you can easily plot a graph with data like:

```
datetime        | lumens
2015-05-12 0900 | 9001
2015-05-12 1000 | 11400
2015-05-12 1100 | 11300
2015-05-12 1200 | 18000
```

Unfortunately the API call, for various reasons such as internet connectivity and the device tragically running from solar power, is intermittent. Ideally the device would store data until it has successfully been collected, but alas it only returns data at the moment it has been asked:

```
datetime        | lumens
2015-05-12 0905 | 9006
2015-05-12 1123 | 11900
2015-05-12 1201 | 18026
```

Which is clearly holey, and often late. Assuming you have to work with this data and create graphs from it, there are several options.

- Use a scattergraph, as this type of graph will account for the irregularity of the data collected
- Interpolate the data to estimate what it would have been, on the hour

Because I want a line graph as I am doing the equivalent of plotting the results from many sensors, I am inclined towards interpolated regularity.

My questions is:

```
if (Does this problem have a name)
  then what is it, so I can look it up
else
  if (Are there better ways of solving this, instead of interpolating regularity)
    then what are they?
  else (ie nope this is the best one)
    then is there a more optimum solution than the following algorithm
  end
end
```

Interpolated regularity pseudocode. (in this pseudocode, on the stack first and pop both look at the earliest value in the array)

```
dataset = the dataset with irregularly spaced readings
results = empty array
first_datetime = Select earliest datetime and select first hour following it (e.g. '2015-05-12 0905' => '2015-05-12 1000') 
last_datetime = Select latest datetime and select first hour preceeding it (e.g. '2015-05-12 1201' => '2015-05-12 1200') 
result_dates = Array of every hour between first_datetime and last_datetime (e.g. ['2015-05-12 1000','2015-05-12 1100','2015-05-12 1200'])
stack = dataset sorted with earliest first to be popped and latest last to be popped
cached_earliest = stack.pop (e.g. '2015-05-12 0905' => 9006)
for each 'result_date' in result_dates
  while stack.first < result_date
    cached_earliest = stack.pop
  end
  results << result_date and interpolation of result_date's value between cached_earliest and stack.first (e.g. working out the value for time '1000' from between '0905'=>9006 and '1123'=>11900 is ((9006*((138-55)/138))+(11900*((138-83)/138))) = ~10159, the gap between the times is 138 minutes)
end
```